# Seeing "error" as text on white when accessing admin

Tags: errors, updates

Honestly, all I did was click "update" on a few plugins and it kicked me out of the admin area. I see "error" as text on a white page.

If I view source on the page, I see:

```
error<!-- wp-login.php -->
```

Already on the newest version of WordPress.

I set `WP_DEBUG` to true, but no luck. Any ideas? Kind of freaking out the site's down and not sure what the next step to debug might be. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is weird. I walked away for coffee, came back, and the error was gone. I was then presented with the WordPress login screen.

Comment: We're *that* good ;)